# Invalid link: Cannot load presenter 'Post', class 'App\Presenters\PostPresenter' was not found

Tags: php, error-handling, nette

I am new to [Nette](http://nette.org/en/) framework, I have done everything correctly but it shows the following warning

[image]

My Files Look like this [image]

Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you try to clean cache (temp\cache)? if it did not help, what are your routes (app\bootstrap.php)?

Comment: Thanks JackDavis, I asked the same question on Nette Forum and a guy figured it out to clear my Cache and it done work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution, I just applied this command `composer dump-autoload` in command prompt which clears the cache :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case `composer dump-autoload` don't help. I must delete temp/cache how advises JackDavis.

The same problem I did with styles, too. After deleting temp/cache is everything ok.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a request for help?

Comment: This is the answer for those who not help dump-autoload. I can not post comments yet. This is answer. Sorry about that.